# How can I send email using mulesoft only once per day?

Tags: mule

I know how to send email using SMTP connector, but the requirement is to send email once per day.

Answer (score 0):

You use a [scheduler](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/scheduler-concept) to trigger a flow once a day, and send the email in the flow. You can use a fixed frequency of 1 day, or a cron expression if you want more detailed definition of the frequency.

Example:

```
<flow name="sendMailFlow">
  <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler">
    <scheduling-strategy >
      <fixed-frequency frequency="1" timeUnit="DAYS"/>
    </scheduling-strategy>
  </scheduler>

  ... SEND MAIL HERE AS USUAL ...

</flow>
```